# Does this quesion have a solution?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, divider

Does this quesion have a solution?
Is it possible to solve for any value or all four?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: What have you been taught regarding resistors in series and also in parallels? How do you calculate the new resistances?

Comment: it looks to me that more info is needed. For example if the current through each branch was give or at least one of the Resistor values was given, Ohms law could be used. This is not a homework quesion. I can easily simulate this and get the answer. I am just curious to see if there is a solution. Total Resistance, and Current was calculated by me, but that is where I got stock.

Comment: you have four unknowns, but only three equations, so it's impossible. You need to add some assumptions to be able to solve for all resistors uniquely, like the current splits equally or in some other known ratio between the two paths.

Comment: I challenge *no effort shown*: \$Total (R)\$ & \$I_{total}\$ seem to be derived from 4.06 V over 20 Ω.

Comment: The current supplied by the generator is 203mA. This current also flows in the parallel, at whose terminals there is a voltage of 5.94V. Therefore the equivalent resistance of the parallel is 5.94V/203mA=29.261_Ohm. The resulting total resistance is R=20_Ohm+29.261_Ohm=49.261Ohm which is different from the provided value 49.23_Ohm.

Comment: You are not welcome to vandalise posts, not even your own. You can delete posts - just consider an ill-regarded question may have useful answers.

Comment: @user355124 - Defacing the question is classed as vandalism and is not allowed. Part of the point of Stack Exchange is to collect questions and their answers *for the future*. The question is now locked to prevent further edits.

Answer (score 3):

It is solvable but you will have a lot of solutions possible. The total current flowing through the 2 resistor branches is fixed but the ratio of currents flowing through them is not constrained. For eg., you can have half current flowing in each branch or 25% in top branch and 75% in bottom branch. Hence multiple solutions possible.